# Epsilon Delta proof for $\lim_{x\to a} x^{1/3}$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Is this proof for limit $\lim_{x\to a} x^{1/3}$ valid?

Lets first find Right Hand limit. $x-a > 0$. Let $x-a < \delta$ so that $x^{1/3}-a^{1/3} < \frac{\delta}{x^{2/3}+x^{1/3}a^{1/3}+a^{2/3}} < \frac{\delta}{a^{2/3}}$

So choosing $\delta = a^{2/3} \varepsilon$, we have $x^{1/3}-a^{1/3} \lt \varepsilon$ whenever $x-a \lt \delta$. Does this complete the proof?

Also I have read that we can choose $\delta$ bigger than what I chose. What does this statement mean? And why can we choose it?

Comment: Are you asking about just the existence of the limit or trying to prove $\lim_{x\to a}x^{1/3}=a^{1/3}$?

Comment: Trying to prove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=0$, then for any $\epsilon>0$

$$|x^{1/3}-a^{1/3}|=|x^{1/3}|<\epsilon$$

whenever $|x|<\delta=\epsilon^3$.

---

If $a> 0$, we first take $x$ such that $\frac{a}{2}<x<\frac{3a}{2}$.

Then, for any $\epsilon>0$

$$\begin{align}
|x^{1/3}-a^{1/3}|&=\frac{|x-a|}{|x^{2/3}+a^{1/3}x^{1/3}+a^{2/3}|}\\\\
&<\frac{|x-a|}{a^{2/3}(1+2^{-1/3}+4^{-1/3})}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $|x-a|<\delta=\min\left(\frac a2,a^{2/3}(1+2^{-1/3}+4^{-1/3})\,\epsilon\right)$.

---

The case $a<0$ is left as an exercise.

Comment: Ok I understand what you did, but is it valid to choose $\delta = a^{2/3}\varepsilon $ ? And can we choose bigger than this delta?

Comment: What if $a$ were $0$?

Comment: Then we use your case, but for other case is my answer fine?

Comment: Please also tell me why any other bigger delta works

Comment: If for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$, then clearly $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta_{\text{Even Smaller}}<\delta$.  That is, if you find a $\delta$ that works, then any number smaller than $\delta$ works also.

Comment: @MarkViola Is there any way that we could avoid case work?

Comment: @prashantsharma How would you propose to do so?